# Do volatile tables truncate results by default?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two queries that supposed to bring equivalent results. However the second query gives only partial results (less than 10 % of the total).

---

First query gives more than 4 million rows

```
SELECT id, amount 
FROM table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2  ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

---

Second give only 18 thousand records

```
CREATE  VOLATILE TABLE vt AS
(
SELECT id, amount 
FROM table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2  ON t1.id = t2.id;
)
WITH DATA
NO PRIMARY INDEX
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

SELECT * 
  FROM vt ;
```

Why does the second query give less records ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a `SHOW TABLE vt;` you'll notice that it's created as a SET table, which doesn't store duplicate rows. There are only 18 thousand distinct (id,amount) combinations.

Either add DISTINCT to your first Select or use CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE.

Comment: Thank you, I did what you said. `Didstinct` reduces 4 million to 2 million. However it is still not right

Comment: I tried `multiset` and `distinct`. Is there any other reason the results would not match? Thanks

Comment: Ooops, i just noticed you created a NoPI table, then it defaults to MULTISET. What if you DELETE all rows from vt and run an INSERT/SELECT?